# JAVAFX. How make TableViewCell editable using FXML?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I want to make TableViewCell using only fxml. How can I do it.

Now I have a model class DuplicateFileInfo

```
class DuplicateFileInfo(var id: Long, var path: String, var editableField: String?) {}
```

And I have TableView

```
<TableView AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="50.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0"
                editable="true"
                layoutX="121.0" layoutY="6.0" fx:id="duplicatesList">
    <columns>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="300.0" text="%file.filename" fx:id="fileNameColumn" editable="false">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="path" />
            </cellValueFactory>
        </TableColumn>
        <TableColumn prefWidth="150.0" text="%file.EditableField" fx:id="editableColumn">
            <cellValueFactory>
                <PropertyValueFactory property="editableField" />
            </cellValueFactory>
            <cellFactory>
                <TextFieldTableCell fx:factory="forTableColumn" />
            </cellFactory>
        </TableColumn>
    </columns>
</TableView>
```

In this case I have editable table view. But the value doesn't set to model after editing is finish.
Is it possible to make this work without codding?

Comment: Not without codddddddddddding the item class appropriately or alternatively using a appropriate `onEditCommit` handler, which needs to be coded too.

Comment: But it is stupid. 
I can read the property without coding. I can make the cell editable without codding. But I couldn' t put the result of editing without coding.

Comment: @AlexeyVashchenkov If you write the model class `DuplicateFileInfo` following the [JavaFX Property Pattern](http://www.oracle.com/pls/topic/lookup?ctx=javase80&id=JFXBD107) then the default implementations of the factories that you are using will work.

Comment: @James_D This doesn't work. After this I have an error 
`javafx.beans.property.SimpleStringProperty cannot be cast to java.lang.String`
Because cellFactory can't be use with SimpleStringProperty

Comment: Then you are not implementing the property pattern correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for James_D
I could get the result.

The model class with kotlin should be like this

```
class DuplicateFileInfo(id: Long, path: String, shouldBeDeleted: Boolean) {

    private val id: LongProperty
    private val path: StringProperty
    private val shouldBeDeleted: BooleanProperty

    init {
        this.id = SimpleLongProperty(id)
        this.path = SimpleStringProperty(path)
        this.shouldBeDeleted = SimpleBooleanProperty(shouldBeDeleted)
    }

    fun getId(): Long {
        return id.get()
    }

    fun idProperty(): LongProperty {
        return id
    }

    fun setId(id: Long) {
        this.id.set(id)
    }

    fun getPath(): String {
        return path.get()
    }

    fun pathProperty(): StringProperty {
        return path
    }

    fun setPath(path: String) {
        this.path.set(path)
    }

    var isShouldBeDeleted: Boolean
        get() = shouldBeDeleted.get()
        set(shouldBeDeleted) = this.shouldBeDeleted.set(shouldBeDeleted)

    fun shouldBeDeletedProperty(): BooleanProperty {
        return shouldBeDeleted
    }

    override fun toString(): String {
        val sb = StringBuffer("DuplicateFileInfo{")
        sb.append("id=").append(id.get())
        sb.append(", path=").append(path.get())
        sb.append(", shouldBeDeleted=").append(shouldBeDeleted.get())
        sb.append('}')
        return sb.toString()
    }
}
```